# How to convert a video to mask with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to synthesize videos with a pre-designed template.

#### template structure

- background video: [background](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/master/ffmpeg/template/38/bg1.mp4)
- mask video: [mask](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/master/ffmpeg/template/38/mask1.mp4)
- foreground video: [foreground](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/master/ffmpeg/template/38/fg1.mp4)
- content video: [content](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/master/python/moviepy_demo/cat.mp4)

The final result is similar to the video below

[result](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/master/python/moviepy_demo/final.mp4) : This video is synthesized by me using moviepy(a Python module for video editing). But it takes too long to be used in production.

**So, I need to overlay these videos into a single video.**

#### Current problems

- How to convert a video to mask by ffmpeg?
- How to synthesize these videos to a single video by ffmpeg?

Comment: These files are all missing now, making this question and answer a little hard to follow for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i cat.mp4 -i bg1.mp4 -i mask1.mp4 -i fg1.mp4 -filter_complex "[2]negate[a];[1][a]alphamerge[frame];[0][frame]overlay=format=auto[framed];[3]mergeplanes=0x00010200:format=yuva420p[fg];[framed][fg]overlay" out.mp4
```

Basic order of ops is 1) attach the mask to the bg video, 2) overlay this result on top of the content. 3) overlay the FG on top of the 2nd result.

For best results, generate a mask for the foreground video as well, and if you do, use alphamerge, like I did for the bg video, instead of mergeplanes, like I've done.

I've had to invert the BG mask as portions colored white represent *visible* areas of the mask.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer,  this is the right solution. But is there any solution that can increase the speed? Because I found that video processing per second takes about 1 second to run (on my Mac). Wish you good health and happy work.

Comment: Add `-preset superfast` after `overlay"`

Comment: ```shell
ffmpeg -i bg1.mp4 -i mask1.mp4 -i fg1.mp4 -i cat.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]negate[m];[0][m]alphamerge[f];[3][f]overlay=format=auto[a];[2]mergeplanes=0x00010200:format=yuva420p[fg];[a][fg]overlay" -preset superfast -y out.mp4
```
It seems that the speed has not improved @Gyan

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Due to comment word limit, here is log ![log](https://github.com/ZeddShi/Gizmos/blob/develop/ffmpeg/template/38/log.txt)

Comment: I get a speed of 3.2x on a Ivy Bridge with `superfast`. I think either your machine has fewer resources or you're using it through some virtual machine or intermediary.

Comment: I tried it many times and the results are the same every time. even on a computer with i7-9700k CPU and Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080ti GPU. Can it be accelerated with my GPU?